# PayPal Express Check Out Sample Code

Tags: jquery, paypal

i want my website integrated to PayPal Express Check Out. I want to know is it possible using JQuery and any example or sample code for me to references... Thank ^^

Answer (score 1):

No. Even if you could, you'd be exposing your own API credentials to everyone.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/ebook/PP_APIReference/expresscheckout.html

```
The Express Checkout API consists of three distinct SOAP requests 
that you make at the three integration points during a customer checkout.
```

You can do SOAP requests via jQuery

http://openlandscape.wordpress.com/2009/09/25/call-soap-xm-web-services-with-jquery-ajax/

**BUT** as you have to have Credentials to communicate with the Paypal API, then you *couldn't* do it with jQuery only (front-end)

```
This example assumes that you have set up the mechanism you will 
use to communicate with the PayPal server and have a PayPal business account 
with API credentials.
```

https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_ECSimpleIntegration

The 2 types of Paypal Credentials :

https://www.paypalobjects.com/IntegrationCenter/ic_certificate.html